# Jest test are failing

Tags: unit-testing, webpack, react-redux, jestjs

Below is issue am getting when I try to run the jest command.

```
jest --config jest.config.json
```

FAIL test\Home.spec.js
? Test suite failed to run

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word  at transformAndBuildScript(node_modules\jest\node_modules\jest-cli\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\transform.js:320:12)
```

Below is my configuration. Package.json with webpack, jest versions

```
    {  
       "name": "testjest",   
       "version": "1.0.0",  
       "description": "Test      React and Redux using Jest",
       "main": "index.js",
       "license": "MIT",
       "scripts": {
       "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base --inline --hot",
       "test": "jest --config jest.config.json"
        },
      "dependencies": {
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
      "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
      "react": "^15.4.1",
      "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
      "react-redux": "^5.0.1",
      "redux": "^3.6.0"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
     "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
     "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
     "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
     "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
     "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
     "core-js": "^2.4.0",
     "enzyme": "^2.7.0",
     "jest": "^18.1.0",
     "json-stable-stringify": "^1.0.1",
     "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.1",
      "react-test-renderer": "^15.4.1",
     "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.1",
     "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.0",
     "regenerator-transform": "^0.10.0",
     "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
     "webpack": "^1.14.0",
     "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
    }
  }
```

Here is my jest json config file.

```
{
 "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "jsx"
 ],
 "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "bower_components", "shared"],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
    "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
  "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
},
"testPathIgnorePatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
  "<rootDir>/legacy_notes_and_workbook/",
  "<rootDir>/src/stylesheets/"
],
"transform": {},
"transformIgnorePatterns": [ "<roodDir>/node_modules/(?!)" , "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-navigation)" ],
   "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.?(test|spec|Test|Spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$"
  }
```

Node versions installed on my machine are:
node -v
v4.2.2

npm -v
1.4.28

Please let me know if anybody has any solution on above issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this  :      `"transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-navigation)"
 ]`

Comment: Tried, that did not help!

Comment: Did you take a look at https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2226 ?